# I can't read integers from a txt file

Tags: c++

I have to use `fstream` to create a `.txt` file and write 0 to 10 in it, then use `fstream` again to read the file and sum all the integers together before outputting the sum to the console.

I can't find where I am making a mistake:

```
fstream myFile;
myFile.open("numbers.txt", ios::in | ios::out);

int sum = 0;
int number = 0;
string line;

if (myFile.is_open()) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        myFile << i;
    }
    myFile.seekp(0, ios::beg);
    while (getline(myFile, line)) {
        myFile >> number;
        sum += stoi(line);
    }
}

cout << "Sum: " << sum << endl;
return 0;
```

I tried `getline()` and other methods, but it didn't work.

Comment: 1. You write 1 to 10, not 0 to 10. 2. The stream pointer is at the file end, of course you can't read lines after the file end.

Comment: close and reopen the file

Comment: In file streams the read and write tracking is the same. If you write to the end of the file, a subsequent read will be from the end of the file. And clearly there's nothing to read if you're at the end of the file.

Comment: I removed `ios::trunc` tried `myFile.close()` it's the same thing, tried to move the pointer by using `myFile.seekp(0)` still same.

Comment: Update the code to show the version where you try to rewind the file.

Comment: You read a line into a variable `std::string line`, and then you go get another number from the file into a variable `int number`, and then you do convert the string to a number but disregard what you stored in `number`.  As a result you're not adding together all the numbers.

Comment: Side note: Program crashes because of [Why does std::getline() skip input after a formatted extraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21567291/4581301) This will be irrelevant after fixing the bug Ben Voigt points out, but still something to watch out for in the future..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing the numbers to the file without any delimiters between them, so the file will contain one long digit sequence in it, ie `012345678910`. You won't be able to make sense of that, no matter how you read it.  So, separate the numbers to make them easier to read.

More importantly, after writing to the file and seeking (the *output* position) to the beginning (rather than seeking the *input* position), you are then calling `getline()` to read the *entire file* into a `std::string`, and then you are trying to convert that entire `string` into an `int`, but the value `012345678910` exceeds the max value that `int` can hold (`2147483647`), so `stoi()` will fail.

You can try this instead:

```
fstream myFile;
myFile.open("numbers.txt", ios::in | ios::out);

int sum = 0;

if (myFile.is_open()) {

    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        myFile << i << ' ';
    }

    myFile.seekg(0, ios::beg);

    int number;
    while (myFile >> number) {
        sum += number;
    }
}

cout << "Sum: " << sum << endl;
```

[Online Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/p9obsEdkh)

However, note that when you are opening the file, you are specifying both the `in` and `out` flags. That will fail if the file *does not already exist* (even if it is blank).  So, if you need to create a new file, the `in` flag must not be specified, but then you can't read from the file, only write to it.  See [this documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open) for `std::basic_filebuf::open()` to understand why.

So, you would have to open the file for writing, then close and reopen it for reading, eg:

```
fstream myFile;

myFile.open("numbers.txt", ios::out);
if (myFile.is_open()) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        myFile << i << ' ';
    }
    myFile.close();
}

int sum = 0;

myFile.open("numbers.txt", ios::in);
if (myFile.is_open()) {
    int number;
    while (myFile >> number) {
        sum += number;
    }
    myFile.close();
}

cout << "Sum: " << sum << endl;
```

[Online Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/ZeH_r9GR5)

In which case, you should use `ifstream` and `ofstream` separately, instead of using `fstream`, eg:

```
ofstream outFile("numbers.txt");
if (outFile.is_open()) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        outFile << i << ' ';
    }
    outFile.close();
}

int sum = 0;

ifstream inFile("numbers.txt");
if (inFile.is_open()) {
    int number;
    while (inFile >> number) {
        sum += number;
    }
    inFile.close();
}

cout << "Sum: " << sum << endl;
```

[Online Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/YXuaiKkST)

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors.

1. When you switch between reading and writing of the same file, you must insert a seek operation in between.
2. Using both `getline(myFile, line)` and `myFile >> number;` makes no sense. One of them must go.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/hjxhb5d95).

PS: the question has been changed, this answer may or may not be valid for its current state.